# How to get a dataframe from XML?

Tags: r, xml

I have a fairly large xml file that I need to convert to a dataframe, but I keep getting an error code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(XML)

xmldata <- xmlInternalTreeParse("C:\\Users\\Lee\\Documents\\R\\housing\\housing_census_2006\\housing_census_2006.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)

housing_census_2006 <- xmlToDataFrame(xmldata)
#> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, names(nodes[[i]]), value = c(ID = "97-554-XCB2006007", : duplicate subscripts for columns
```

The error is occuring when I try to use xmlToDataFrame. Is there something wrong with my code or is this not the right way to do it?

For clarification, this is what the xml file looks like (this is just one record):

```
-<generic:Series>

-<generic:SeriesKey>

<generic:Value value="01" concept="GEO"/>

<generic:Value value="1" concept="B06_Hhtype1CFOnly"/>

<generic:Value value="1" concept="B06_HhMainAge"/>

</generic:SeriesKey>


-<generic:Obs>

<generic:Time>2006</generic:Time>

<generic:ObsValue value="12437470"/>

</generic:Obs>

</generic:Series>
```

Comment: Hard/impossible to answer without actual sample data.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post with an example of how the data looks.

Comment: i suggest takeing a look at the `xml2` package and extract data needed manually.

Comment: Your sample is not well-formed since it includes a namespace prefix, `generic`, but no where is this prefix defined. Always include the root node (usually defines namespaces) with XML samples.